# Slow redraw of TableViewer when changing input object

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

In my project, I have a `TableViewer` which displays about 1k rows of data from database. The `ContentProvider` is an `ArrayContentProvider`.

When I change input the List (`setInput()` on `TableViewer` object) to another one with the same amount of data, everything is Ok. But when I want to update it with `List<T>` with different size than the previous one, the application freezes for about 10x the time of changing with same amount of data.

The first list has a size of 1k, and the second list a size of about 960. Execution freezes directly on `setInput()` method.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: TableViewer does a lot of things in the setInput method; getting the elements as an array, sorting, filtering, comparing to old list items etc... I'd probably check the toArray method on whatever list implementations you have first as they will be easy to benchmark/eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that when you set a List with a different size the whole native TableItems are recreated. So to speed up your table you should use a SWT.Virtual style table. With virtual table only the tableitems which are displayed are created. The others are created when you scroll.

See http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet029VirtualTableViewer.java for an example.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Unfortunately, I already use this style on TableViewer, and it didn't help. What is interesting, on change to smaller size, table loads correctly, but when then I want to load bigger list, than it hangs up.

Comment: You should use a profiler to analyze the problem. The profiler will show you what is your code doing while freezing.